# Vim: read modeline after opening the file?

Tags: bash, shell, vim, modeline

I work on a variety of projects and many of them set file-specific vim settings. I have been asked to not have modelines set in .vimrc; is there a way after loading the file to load the modelines settings?

So if I open tmp.c with vim:

```c
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    return 0;
}

/* vim: set expandtab tabstop=4 : */
```

Is there a command I can run to set the stuff in the modeline? Just doing `:set modeline` after it is open doesn't do anything.

Comment: After `:set modeline`, reload the file with `:e`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf You should write this as an answer.

Answer (score 14):

After `:set modeline`, reload your buffer with `:e`.

Answer (score 12):

If you do not want to reload the buffer (e.g. because it contains unpersisted changes, or to avoid clearing the undo history), you can use the fact that a `:doautocmd` triggers modeline processing:

```
:set modeline | doautocmd BufRead
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! But how can I disable it afterwards? I posted a question, answer there please: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64368210/9391770)

Answer (score 3):

You can tell vim to execute arbitrary commands *before* sourcing your `~/.vimrc`:

```
$ vim --cmd "set modeline" yourfile
```