# Vim: disable autocmd BufRead (modeline)

Tags: vim, disable, autocmd, modeline

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24233643/9391770) I executed:

```
:set modeline | doautocmd BufRead
```

Since then, I cannot disable the *BufRead*.

I can open a file and unset the *modeline*:

```
:set nomodeline
:e!
:wq
```

But when I reopen the same file, its *modeline* is again auto executed.

I tried [noautocmd](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#:noautocmd) - [autocmd-remove](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#autocmd-remove):

```
:noautocmd w BufRead
:noautocmd BufRead
:exe "au! BufRead *"
:au! BufRead
```

Note I want to disable all auto executed because of *BufRead*, not just a single *event* set by it like here explained: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40173033/9391770

Comment: I think you got a bit confused by the `BufRead` - that event only got creatively reused for `:doautocmd` (any event would do) so that modelines are re-executed without reloading the buffer - what the linked question is about. Now you seem to be asking for the _opposite_ - preventing modelines from loading.

Comment: I think you get mixed results from `:set nomodeline` because it is a buffer-local option - only buffers opened from the current buffer will observe that. To persist that, the command has to be put into your `~/.vimrc` file, or use `:setglobal nomodeline`. To turn off modelines altogether, you can also `:set modelines=0` - this option is a global one, so easier to handle.

Comment: Thank you very much @IngoKarkat! Nice explanation. I tried little by little, but in files that I executed before `:set modeline | doautocmd BufRead` I could only prevent from running modelines once in .vimrc I put your code `:set modelines=0`, like `:setglobal nomodeline` alone in .vimrc was not enough.

Comment: Furthermore  @Ingo, I created a map for running modeline in trusted files only, can you check it? please.  `nnoremap <leader>mdl <Esc>:set modelines=5<space><bar><space>:set modeline<space><bar><space>:e<space><bar><space>:set modelines=0<space><bar><space>:set nomodeline<CR>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the linked question, the `BufRead` event only got creatively reused for `:doautocmd` (any event would do) so that modelines are re-executed without reloading the buffer. Now you're asking for the opposite - preventing modelines from loading.

The corresponding options are [`'modeline'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27modeline%27) and [`'modelines'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27modelines%27) - if the former is off or the latter is set to `0`, modelines are ignored.

Your given mapping looks fine to me; it can be simplified a bit; you don't need to spell out `<space>` (only `<bar>`), and the `:` can be dropped except at the front, where it is used for the transition from normal mode to command-line mode. A prepended `<C-u>` will clear any count (should you accidentally supply some).

```
:nnoremap <leader>mdl :<C-u>set modelines=5<bar>set modeline<bar>edit <bar>set modelines=0<bar>set nomodeline<CR>
```

#### Simplification with plugin

The [anwolib plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3800) has a nifty `:With {setlocal-args} Do {cmd}` command; if you just target the (buffer-local) `'modeline'` option for toggling (which at least for me is sufficient), the whole mapping can be written as

```
:nnoremap <leader>mdl :<C-u>With modeline Do edit<CR>
```

This is so crisp and understandable that you barely need a mapping any longer!

#### Security impact of modelines

Modelines can only change Vim options - some are even forbidden to change because those could be exploited; it is not possible to execute arbitrary Vim commands through them. Though some attacks can be imagined (especially if you have some plugins or customizations which act on changed buffer options), modelines in general are safe. So unless you're paranoid about security or work in an environment with stringent security requirements, you usually don't need to take such precautions. Of course, if you don't personally use modelines at all, turning them off reduces the attack surface. But at least for me, the effort to recognize that modelines would be handy to execute and then toggle the setting and reload the buffer would be worse than the minimal risk that they pose.

Comment: Excellent answer!! For futures noobies with same problem, check also Mr. Karkat comments in the question itself, there is pointed out that for persistent effect these set options (`modeline` and `modelines`) should appear in $MYVIMRC (normally ~/.vimrc).